# Many to many relationship doesn't exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have registration form generated through php artisan make:auth command in Laravel project. I want to customize it a bit by adding functionality that user can select his/her gender when registering. I made genders table that has genders column with two values Man and Woman and also added gender_user table with gender_id and user_id column. I made many to many relationship but when I try and register user I get error that says

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::genders does not exist.
```

And it writes user in users table but in gender_user table it doesn't write anything. My relationship is tested and it works when I try and get user with genders relation from another controller. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'genders' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            /* 'gender_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.genders,id',
            'user_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.users,id', */
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:18'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $genders = DB::table('genders') 
            ->whereIn(
                'genders',
                [
                    request()->genders
                ]
            )
            ->pluck('id')
            ->toArray();

        //dd($genders);

        $user = User::create([
            //'genders' => $data['genders'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        //dd($user);

        $newUser = User::find($user);

        $newUser->genders()->attach($genders);

        dd($newUser);

        return User::find($user);

    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'age',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function genders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gender::class, 'gender_user', 'user_id', 'gender_id');
    }

    public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Gender.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gender extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'gender_user', 'gender_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

gender_user table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGenderUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gender_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('gender_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')
                ->on('genders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('gender_user');
    }
}
```

genders table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGendersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('genders');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('genders');
    }
}
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="genders" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Genders') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="genders" class="form-control @error('genders') is-invalid @enderror" name="genders" value="{{ old('genders') }}" required autocomplete="genders">
                                    <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
                                    <option value="Woman Looking For Woman">Woman Looking For Woman</option>
                                    <option value="Man">Man</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('genders')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="age" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Age') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="age" class="form-control @error('age') is-invalid @enderror" name="age" value="{{ old('age') }}" required autocomplete="age">
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('age')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Why are you declaring `$newUser = User::find($user);` ? your model is already right there, in $user.

Comment: the relation concept does not make sense. a user can have a single gender. right?? add the gender id in the user table and use belongs to relationship.

Comment: *"a user can have a single gender. right??"* ... now *there's* a can of worms to open...

Comment: @CD001 Yeah, I realize that maybe I didn't put right relationship, but nevertheless the error is resolved.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I added gender_id in users table and in User model belongsTo and in Gender model hasOne. Can you tell me how to write in RegisterController to attach user with correct gender (gender_id)?

Comment: you don't need the `hasOne` relationship as multiple users can have the same gender. and while registering user just save the gender id in the user table.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Can you help on how to write code for that? I am trying but for some reason I am unable to write gender_id in column

Comment: i have added an answer for you..check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon your request i am writing an answer for you. so first start with the database table.

Gender

```
Schema::create('genders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('genders');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

User

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->unsignedInteger('gender_id')->index();
    //other attributes as per your need
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

> i am using soft delete to be safe when some parent is deleted but still i need the child row and the relationship.

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'age', 'gender_id'
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function gender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gender::class, 'gender_id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Gender Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Gender extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes; 

    /**
    * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
    *
    * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    //the relation is not necessary. but if you want how many users belongs
    to a single gender you can determine from this relationship
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'gender_id');
    }
}
```

Register Form

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="genders" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Genders') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="genders" class="form-control @error('genders') is-invalid @enderror" name="gender_id" value="{{ old('gender_id') }}" required autocomplete="genders">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    @forelse($genders as $gender)
                                    <option value="{{ $gender->id }}" 
                                    @if( old('gender_id') == $gender->id )
                                       selected
                                    @endif>
                                    {{ $gender->genders }}
                                    </option>
                                    @empty
                                    <option value="">No Gender Found</option>
                                    @endforelse
                                </select>
                                @error('genders')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="age" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Age') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="age" class="form-control @error('age') is-invalid @enderror" name="age" value="{{ old('age') }}" required autocomplete="age">
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('age')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Register Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'genders' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'gender_id' => ['required', Rule::notIn(['','0'])],
            'user_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.users,id', */
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:18'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'gender_id' => $data['gender_id'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $user;

    }
}
```

and finally RegistersUsers trait (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Gender;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $genders = Gender::all();
        return view('auth.register',compact('genders');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

feel free to ask anything you don't understand. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

When changing the code to

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $genders = Gender::whereIn(
            'genders',
            [
                request()->genders
            ]
        )
        ->pluck('id')
        ->toArray();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'age' => $data['age'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->genders()->attach($genders);

    return $user;

}
```

It works fine now